# Does the MacBook Air Support 5.1 Surround Sound

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, audio

The title pretty much says it all.  I have a 13" version of the newest-generation MBA.  Can I get 5.1 surround sound?  If so, do I have to do anything special to enable it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not natively, no. The headphone jack is a standard TRS with no optical component.

You can buy a USB sound "card" with 5.1 audio output such as this one:

[http://www.amazon.com/Zalman-ZM-RSSC-External-Sound-Card/dp/B0001OZ2K8](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0001OZ2K8)

That's just the first one I found, so a little more market research might be in order. Something similar to it should get the job done though.

Comment: To elaborate the computer will support surround sound, just has no way to output it. You will need a Thunderbolt to HDMI adapter or something like what @eyemyth linked to.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get 5.1 out with an HDMI cable and a suitable HDMI switch with optical or other 5.1 out.  Note that running HDMI through a TV (or even possibly certain receivers) likely won't work, because of anti-piracy hardware that restricts output audio quality.  There are a number of cheap switches that people have done this with.  I don't want to suggest anything specific as I haven't used them myself.  You can also get 5.1 audio out from an Airport Express's audio jack.  Unfortunately the Airport Extreme has no audio out (at least not the model I have).